# How to set first page as a different page without header and footer using Apache POI?

Tags: apache-poi

Using Word, I want to remove first header footer and set first page as a different page.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what did you observe? Please see [ask] and edit your question with more information

Comment: I want to remove header footer from 1st page only

Comment: _What have you tried so far and what did you observe?_ (and did you read [ask]?) Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service, but we're happy to point out flaws or required changes _in your code_. If you provide what you've tried so far, you might get an answer. If you don't, you risk the question to be closed. Maybe the article about [mcve] helps you come up with something relevant